# Sonarqube unit-test reports history (reports for previous versions of a project)

Tags: sonarqube

I was looking for a way to look at the unit-test report of  a project for older version.
I can see the last published report with details of which tests were run(list of classes), failed, success...; but cannot get the same for previous versions (only failed %, total no. of tests was available in history; but no class names list) published a few minutes before.
I had set the sonar.dbCleaner properties for more than 30days.

Thanks in advance.
P.S. using sonarqube version 6.5LTS

Comment: sonarQube does not retain information for previous builds.

Comment: Thanks @prasad; I felt the same, as it was not mentioned anywhere in the docs.